# Is there any ngComponentRouter CDN?

Tags: angularjs, google-cdn, ngcomponentrouter

Is there any official CDN from google that have the ngComponentRouter, I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there isn't any CDN partner of google that implemented it but you could use this [publication](https://github.com/excellalabs/ngComponentRouter).

Here you can find the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component-router)

Be aware it has been deprecated and they recommend to use ngRoute module.

Answer (score 1):

It's not google or minified, but I use https://npmcdn.com/@angular/router@0.2.0/angular1/angular_1_router.js